# Find the average of ids in a month

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, count

I can calculate the number of ids in a month and then sum it up over 12 months. I also get the average using this code.

```
select id, to_char(event_month, 'yyyy') event_year, sum(cnt) overall_count, avg(cnt) average_count
from (
    select id, trunc(event_date, 'month') event_month, count(*) cnt
    from daily 
    where event_date >= date '2019-01-01' and event_date < '2019-01-31'
    group by id, trunc(event_date, 'month')
) t
group by id, to_char(event_month, 'yyyy')
```

The results looks something like this:

```
ID| YEAR | OVER_ALL_COUNT| AVG
 1| 2019 | 712           | 59.33
 2| 2019 | 20936849      | 161185684.6
 3| 2019 | 14255773      | 2177532.2
```

However, I want to modify this to get the over all id counts for a month instead and the average of the id counts per month. Desired result is:

```
ID| MONTH | OVER_ALL_COUNT| AVG
 1| Jan   | 152            | 10.3
 2| Jan   | 15000          | 1611
 3| Jan   | 14255          | 2177
 1| Feb   | 4300           | 113
 2| Feb   | 9700           | 782
 3| Feb   | 1900           | 97
```

where January has 152 id counts over all for id=1, and the average id count per day is 10.3. For id=2, the january count is 15000 and the average id=2 count for jan is 1611.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the truncating on your subquery to truncate by day instead of by month, then truncate the outer query by month instead of year.

```sql
select id, to_char(event_day, 'Mon') event_month, sum(cnt) overall_count, avg(cnt) average_count
from (
    select id, trunc(event_date) event_day, count(*) cnt
    from daily 
    where event_date >= date '2019-01-01' and event_date < date '2019-01-31'
    group by id, trunc(event_date)
) t
group by id, to_char(event_month, 'Mon')
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `last_day()`:

```
select id, to_char(event_month, 'yyyy') event_year, sum(cnt) as overall_count,
       avg(cnt) as average_count,
       extract(day from last_day(min(event_month)) as days_in_month,
       sum(cnt) / extract(day from last_day(min(event_month)) as avg_days_in_month
from (select id, trunc(event_date, 'month') as event_month, count(*) as cnt
      from daily 
      where event_date >= date '2019-01-01' and
            event_date < date '2020-01-01'
      group by id, trunc(event_date, 'month')
     ) t
group by id, to_char(event_month, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! I realized I didn't frame the question properly I have updated the question.